# Receive Raw HEX by socket and convert to string

Tags: c#, sockets, character-encoding, hex, data-conversion

I have the following problem, I try to receive raw HEX value from a TCP/IP socket and write them down in a txt file, Only I am having some problems converting this raw HEX data to a UTF-8 string. I am using the following method:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.200.91", 2101);
NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();
byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
netStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)client.ReceiveBufferSize);

string returndata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\ -\Documents\test.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.WriteLine(returndata);
}
```

This returns : `*þý%     ˆ   ê‡… ÿ  Œ7ºe B  %û`

How to successfully read the raw HEX data and convert this into a readable string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BitConverter:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.200.91", 2101);
NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();
byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
int bytesRead = netStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)client.ReceiveBufferSize);

string returndata = BitConverter.ToString(bytes, 0, bytesRead).Replace("-", "")

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\ -\Documents\test.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.WriteLine(returndata);
}
```

Comment: Major thanks, do you have any idea where all the 0 come from?

Comment: Yeah, you're reading the buffer size.  I'll update my answer. One moment.

Comment: @ErwinVorenhout That should fix it so that it only uses the bytes read from the stream now.

Comment: 2AFEFD25010000000000018E000002000EEA878500FF00000A0000000000008C37BA658F0042000027ED That whas the trick, thanks man!